# Bootstrap4-alpha - make grid layout take 100% of size and row take a percentage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem regarding bootstrap v4-alpha. After looking around here I already tried somethings and had no luck. Here is what I am trying:-

```css
 
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
          }
          .green{
            background-color: Green;
          }
          .dgreen{
            background-color: #006400;
          }
          .fill {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
          }
```

```html
  
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
      <div class="row h-10">
        <div class="col-md-10 green">Titel</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 dgreen">Nr</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row h-90">
        <div class="col-md-10 dgreen">Content</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 green">Sidebar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to make my layout cover the full site and then make the rows and columns take a certain percentage of it. But in the dev-Tools of Chrome it does not seem to take the full height.

As you can see I have already found some pieces of code and samples here but had no luck. 
Thanks if you can help.

Comment: In bootstrap `h-10` and `h-90` are not given still if you want to use , give your own css for this.

Comment: Ok thanks I have added those classes on my own. But the container is not at heigth 100%

Comment: Now please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this css for cover full screen height.

```
.container-fluid.h-100 {
  height: 100vh !important;
}
```

```css
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.green{
  background-color: Green;
}
.dgreen{
  background-color: #006400;
}
.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.h-90 {
  height: 90%;
}
.h-10 {
  height: 10%;
}
.container-fluid.h-100 {
  height: 100vh !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-10">
    <div class="col-md-10 green">Titel</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 dgreen">Nr</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-90">
    <div class="col-md-10 dgreen">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 green">Sidebar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 not support height for 10% and 90%.
You can use 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100%